# Texture appears differently across surfaces of a complex object?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am currently using a `UV Map` node and a `Mapping` node to control the texture over a complex object.

Weirdly, the texture appears dramatically differently across the object. Specifically, on some surfaces, texture looks just right, whereas on some other surfaces, the texture suddenly becomes barely visible, as shown below.

[image]

Here is my model.

[image]

How may I make the texture look the same everywhere?

P.S.: Since (1) I am building an automatic pipeline, (2) the object is very complicated in geometry, and (3) it's not necessary to have a specific texture, it's not feasible to specify a UV map, so I am looking for an "automatic" solution like `Generated Coordinates`.

Comment: So what is the question? There is nothing weird about it, if you are using a UV Map node the Blender reading the UV coordinates from the specified UV map, and applying the to the texture. If the density is not uniform then you need to unwrap with the desired density. Without sharing your node setup, material settings and UV Maps there is not much we ca say about it

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've supplemented in the question my node setup -- hopefully, it is clear. Could you kindly help share how to "unwrap with the desired density"?

Comment: You use a UVMap node but you don't specify a UVMap name. Can you show your object's UV Map? Did you ever unwrap your object before applying a texture? [Blender Unwraping Tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender+unwrapping)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks again! Shape of my object is so weird (please see the updated question) that I cannot mark seams (which I think is necessary for unwrapping?). So you are right -- I didn't unwrap my object. Appreciate your kind help!

Comment: Well unwrapping is pretty much a laborious manual work of trial and error until you get the desired effect, there is really no recipe for success here. I'd probably start by trying making seams around the edges, but I am no unwrapping expert. Alternatively If don't need a very specific texture shape or flow you may try one of the procedural solutions with a *Texture Coordinates* node, like *Object* or *Generated*, results are much less flexible, but a lot easier to achieve

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Right, I don't need a specific texture shape or flow. However when I use `Generated` of `Texture Coordinates` node, the same thing happens -- on one surface, the texture density seems alright, but on another surface, the texture is super dense. What should I do to fix it? Thanks again Sir!

Comment: I have no clue, without seeing your end result, or your node setup its impossible to recommend anything. Please edit your question and provide more details, like screenshots, or a reference image of what you want it to look like, or perhaps a [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) we can look at

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos you are definitely correct Sir. I've uploaded my model and made my question clearer. Please see above. Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic UV coordinates will yield relatively uniform and consisten texture densities across your mesh, with little effort too, at the expense of control and flexibility.

They *will* inevitably produce distortions of parts of the mesh, since they are blindly projected from a predefined point, without any regard for mesh topology or shape. They should however maintain an overall constant density distortions aside.

[image: Motiontrail Generated]

If you wish to have better results at the expense of a lot more manual work you should go with the proper texturing workfow and use actual UV Coordinates by unwrapping your mesh.

This is a manual process, and the texture density will only be as uniform as your UV map quality and unwrapping skills will dictate.

I was able to achieve relatively good UV quality from the <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap > Follow Active Quads > Even* option, with a fresh UV layer, on part of your mesh.

It yielded a relatively good and even quads grid. This is how a good UV map would look.

[image: Motiontrail UV Unwrapped]

Again I can't stress enough that by default there is absolutely no obligation that your UVs will be uniform under any circumstances, you have to manually make them uniform by eyeballing and visually scaling every UV island so it matches your desired density.

Comment: Also see related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73469/uv-stretching-on-a-cylinder