# UV Stretching on a cylinder

Tags: uv

I'm a bit confused about why a cylinder I am trying to unwrap is giving me stretching issues:

[image]

I have applied scaling to my object and the UV map itself looks fine to me. Interesting, if I reduce the height of the cylinder, I can get the UV squares to be more uniform so it seems to be a scaling issue of some kind. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to scale Y the part of the UV map surrounded in red

Comment: Those are not stretching issues, your UV coordinates are naturally stretched so the texture appears correspondingly stretched. UV Mapping doesn't necessarily give undistorted results by default, you have to manually make them so, so as mentioned by lemon fix it by scaling in the Y axis.

Comment: Or scale it up by X (or down by Y). In other words, change ratio for that part - as of now X is too small, Y is too large.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Texture appears differently across surfaces of a complex object?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73419/texture-appears-differently-across-surfaces-of-a-complex-object)