# Advanced UV unwrap and bump map / displacement problems

Tags: uv, displacement, height-map

First post here! I've been searching and searching and can't find a solution to my problem.

So basically I'm wanting to model myself a ring with the surface of the moon on it.

So the first route I thought of was to try and UV map the top surface of the ring then I could maybe use a bump map to get the geometry I want. But when I tried to unwrap using the follow active quads it didn't unwrap in a uniform way allowing my to get a realistic surface of the moon.

[image]

So I then tried separating the surface that will have the moon texture on and tried applying a displacement modifier, but cannot figure out how to get control over how the image is stretched and hence displaced on the surface.

[image]

I've watched hours of tutorials to no avail and would really appreciate some help on firstly the best way to achieve my desired results and secondly how to get around my problems!

Comment: Part of the mesh which is supposed to have a texture shouldn't be separated from the main one. Follow Active QUads probably didin't work as desired because it's better to unwrap one face and straighten it, and then leaving that face as active use Follow Active Quads. Or just unwrap with seams and U > Unwrap. As the mesh isn't complex one seam will be enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Texture appears differently across surfaces of a complex object?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73419/texture-appears-differently-across-surfaces-of-a-complex-object)

Comment: My post maybe wasn't worded correctly. I want the mesh to be physically deformed, not just a textured, but I think I still need to unwrap the part of the band I want to displace first? 
Thanks for the tip on active quads!

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it should be textured or deformed - as you want Displace modifier to use UV coordinates for texture (also called displacement map) you need to unwrap at least that part of the mesh which is supposed to be deformed (or all the mesh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I think I've done what you appear to be attempting and using of all things a moon map texture designed to be unwrapped on a sphere, certain I'd have the same problem.

I UV unwrapped it using 'Smart Unwrap' and got good results albeit with one section showing an annoying area at repeated intervals.

Because this was aligned along the ring's circular surface , I went into the UV editor and rotated the image 90 degrees.  Then rescaled and dragged all the outer surfaces in the editor to eliminate that pattern.

The end result -

[image]

Comment: I am still working out the kinks in the UV editor, but even still the result I'm getting doesn't quite look like yours, but somewhat fuzzy, so the result looks nothing like the topology effect I'm after, and what you have achieved.
http://imgur.com/IxsGPVn

Comment: I can upload the Blender file if you wish but all I've done there is add some "Bumping", but only to the outer surface.  That's in in the textures properties under the "Influence" tab, tick the Geometry box and adjust the "Normals" slider, see the difference!

Comment: That would be fantastic if you wouldn't mind. In the mean time I will play around with my own model and see where I get.
Thanks again!!

Comment: Blend file has been added to the Ans Max.  Have packed the texture (image) file with it.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted, or at least upvote it.