# UV Unwrap Problem

Tags: uv

[image]

I just want to ask why the uv layout is not perfect like the object? i need the perfect circle for sewing pattern, but the uv got problem, pls help me thanks so much in advance ^^

Comment: Because you use NGons. Ngons are more than 4-sided faces and cause problems with nearly all known workflows sooner or later, so should be avoided in most cases.

Comment: then, what should i do to fix this sir? and i dont know what is Ngons ^^ thanks to your answer

Comment: This might help with modelling http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/ and this might help with UV unwrapping http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/74045#74045 also this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73419/texture-appears-differently-across-surfaces-of-a-complex-object/73533#73533