# Smart UV Project: the sequence of the faces is wrong and has inconsistent width

Tags: uv

I’m new to Blender, been using it less than a month. I created a small tower, and am now trying to apply a texture.

My issue is in the Unwrapping, I get the best result from Smart UV Project. When it unwraps however the sequence of the faces is wrong and the width of the face panels in the UV/Image Editor are incorrect. It makes my seamless texture not so seamless.

Scale is set to 1.000 for X,Y & Z. The doors and windows were created using a Boolean Modifier.

Seams Layout and Face selection order
[image: Seams & Face Selection Order]

Unwrapped Cylinder
[image: UV Unwrap]

So how do I go about unwrapping it in order and scaled correctly? Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try other uv unwrapping modes? if you can, provide the file through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then post the provided link in the question, it would help to find the best way.

Comment: I did try others. All of them. The closest I got was with the Smart UV Project. I tried to add the link to the post but it would not let me. Something about Reputation Points? This is the link --> [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4000" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4000/)

Comment: Smart UV Project **does not** guarantee consistent scale at all, nor do any other methods. Your model has ngons which are largely regarded as [bad topology](http://topologyguides.com) and will only make it worse. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56748/help-with-smart-uv and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73419/texture-appears-differently-across-surfaces-of-a-complex-object

Answer (score 1):

I think you can work a bit on this: I tried with your file and got some decent result, imho.

The first thing is: I isolated just the exterior walls.

[image]

then I set the front view and unwrapped cylindrical

[image]

I got an (extremely high) quite nice square unwrap

[image]

but helping with 2d cursor and the pivot choice, it's easy to scale it dow to make it a bit more manageable

[image]

[image]

[image]

then I loaded a brick wall image similar to yours

[image]

and aligned and scaled the uv map to the image

what about the face sequence? it seems ok, look them while I select (in top view) all faces...

[image]

Hth..

Comment: Thats Awesome. Works very well and with a bit of work you can get really good results. Thanks for the shove in the right direction.